# Undefined offset error in PHP 2d array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

EDIT: Code is viewable here: http://codepad.org/28XT71AB

I've searched, but nothing seems to come up quite like my problem.

Before I start: I have put all the code that could be the problem below. This is about 200 lines of code, and I am terribly sorry! But I'm totally stumped.

I have a 2D array, `$val` which is populated by a function.

The array is then passed to another function, which uses the data to populate a table.

The problem only arose once I split my one function into two.

I had one function, which would get a load of data, populate the 2D array with it, and then would create the display for that data. i decided to split it - one function to populate the array, and another function to display this data in the format required.

However, since splitting the function in two, even with careful analysis of the code, for some reason the array is either not being populated properly, or is not being read properly, or something else has gone wrong.

Included is the dump of my code, since clearly my own eyes cannot spot the issue.

Sorry, it is a lot of code. But I have gone through every line and can't work out what's wrong - especially since when it was one function it worked fine!

The undefined offset error loops at the points indicated in the below code.

Global variables and first function - getting the data out of a CSV.

```
/*
  variables that work out current week
*/

$termstart = strtotime("03 October 2011"); //start of term, set manually every year, week 1 is first week after freshers.
$todaysdate = strtotime("now"); //todays date
$weekdif = ceil(($todaysdate-$termstart)/604800);//weeks between the two dates
//define global variables and arrays
$row = 0;
$col = 0;
$num = 0;


//this is the main timetable interface array
$val = array(array());

$ttdata = array();

$lecs = array();

tableinit($weekdif);


function tableinit($wkd)
{

$days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
$times = array("09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00");


//Check for appropriate CSV file and open it
if (($handle = fopen("timetable.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    //Check file for data and copy it into an array
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        //filter out blank lines in the file
        $fdata = array_filter($data);
        $num = count($fdata);

        //If line is not empty
        if ($num > 0)
        {
            //for every value in the array (the line)
            for ($c=0; $c<$num; $c++)
            {

                /*
                  This gets the module code, trims it of useless data,
                  then adds the name into an array of lectures for comparison later.
                  This is used to set up different colours for each different module
                */

                if ($c == 3)
                {
                    $lecture = substr($fdata[$c],0,8);

                    if (empty($lecs))
                    {
                        $lecs[] = $lecture;
                    }
                    else if (!(in_array($lecture,$lecs)))
                    {
                        $lecs[] = $lecture;
                    }

                    $ttdata[] = $lecture;
                }

                //if it's the 4th value or higher, then its data we want to display.
                if ($c >= 4)
                {
                    //add the data to an array. If no array exists, create it
                    $ttdata[] = $fdata[$c];
                }



                /*
                  if the value is a day of the week
                  set the value of the first timetable column as the appropriate day
                  with the corresponding row
                */

                switch ($fdata[$c])
                {
                    case $days[0]:
                        $row = 0;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[1]:
                        $row = 1;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[2]:
                        $row = 2;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[3]:
                        $row = 3;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[4]:
                        $row = 4;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[5]:
                        $row = 5;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                    case $days[6]:
                        $row = 6;
                        $val[$row][0] = $fdata[$c];
                        break;
                }

                /*
                  this function compares the current week to the weeks in the timetable.
                  If there's a match, add a flag to the array for that lecture.
                  if not, do nothing.
                */

                if ($c == 6)
                {
                    $exp1 = explode(",", $fdata[$c]);

                    foreach ($exp1 as $i)
                    {
                        $i = trim($i);
                        $exp2 = explode("-", $i);

                        if (($wkd >= $exp2[0])&&($wkd <= $exp2[1]))
                        {
                            $ttdata[] = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }

                /*
                  if c the second value in the array,
                  check the value against the Time array
                  and set the column appropriately
                */
                if ($c==1)
                {
                    switch ($fdata[$c])
                    {
                        case $times[0]:
                            $col = 1;
                            break;
                        case $times[1]:
                            $col = 2;
                            break;
                        case $times[2]:
                            $col = 3;
                            break;
                        case $times[3]:
                            $col = 4;
                            break;
                        case $times[4]:
                            $col = 5;
                            break;
                        case $times[5]:
                            $col = 6;
                            break;
                        case $times[6]:
                            $col = 7;
                            break;
                        case $times[7]:
                            $col = 8;
                            break;
                        case $times[8]:
                            $col = 9;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } //end line

            //fill the timetable with whitespace to preserve shape and empty slots
            for ($i=0;$i<=6;$i++)
            {
                for ($j=1;$j<=9;$j++)
                {
                    if (!isset($val[$i][$j]))
                    {
                        $val[$i][$j] = "&nbsp;";
                    }
                }
            }

            //if there's a flag to display data
            if (isset($ttdata[4]))
            {
                //remove the flag
                unset($ttdata[4]);
                //fill the current timetable position with the array of data to display
                $val[$row][$col] = $ttdata;
            }

            //delete the array of data to display
            unset($ttdata);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);//close the file when finished
}

}
```

Second function (drawing the table)

```
drawtable($weekdif, $val);

function drawtable($wkd, $val)
{

$days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
$times = array("09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00");


//this sets up any days with no lectures, so there's not just a blank line
for ($m=0;$m<5;$m++)
{
    $row=$m;
    $val[$row][0] = $days[$m];
}

//create the table for the data from the main array
$table = "<table class='main' align='center'>\n<tr><td>Week $wkd</td>";

//create the line of different lecture times in the first row of the table
foreach ($times as $t)
{
    $table .= "<td class='dt'> ". $t . "</td>";
}
$table .= "</tr>\n"; //end first row

//for every weekday
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    //create a new row
    $table .= "<tr>";

    //for every time slot on that day
    for ($j=0;$j<=9;$j++)
    {
        //if there's an array present
        if (is_array($val[$i][$j]) == TRUE) //LOOP IS HERE
        {
            //copy the array to a temporary one
            $temp = $val[$i][$j];

            /*
              Switch statement to ensure that each module is always shown as a different colour.
              the same module will always be the same colour. Different modules will always be different colours.
            */

            switch ($temp[0])
            {
                case $lecs[0]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture1'>";
                    break;
                case $lecs[1]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture2'>";
                    break;
                case $lecs[2]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture3'>";
                    break;
                case $lecs[3]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture4'>";
                    break;
                case $lecs[4]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture5'>";
                    break;
                case $lecs[5]:
                    $table .= "<td class='lecture6'>";
                    break;
            }
            //for each value in the array
            foreach ($temp as $datum)
            {
                //print it and create a new line
                $table .= " ". $datum . " <br />";
            }
            $table .= "</td>";
        }
        //otherwise if a Day is present
        elseif ($j==0)
        {
            //print it
            $table .= "<td class='dt'>";
            $table .= $val[$i][$j]; //LOOP IS HERE
            $table .= "</td>";
        }
        //otherwise
        else
        {
            //print the whitespace
            $table .= "<td class='tt'>";
            $table .= $val[$i][$j];
            $table .= "</td>";
        }

    }
    //end row
    $table .= "</tr>\n";
}
//end table
$table .= "</table>";

//print the entire table
echo $table;

}
```

Finally, to see the error in action:

http://oliverlea.com/3yp/tt.php

Comment: does this code make up your entire tt.php because I don't get 319 lines?

Comment: You should put the code onto some code-pad like http://codepad.org/

Comment: Ah, no. there are 23 lines above where i start quoting my code, which set up the page doctype, import in jquery and my own js file, set up the css, etc. the php code is all there, however. I did make a note of the two lines the error come up on in my massive code snippets ( as `//LOOP IS HERE` )

Comment: can you add the full code instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `tableinit` access to the `$val` variable with the `global` keyword:

```
  function tableinit($wkd) {
        global $val;
```

See PHP's manual page on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Without the `global` keyword, your function is creating a local version of `$val` and manipulating that, but the `$val` you define at the top of your page remains unchanged.

Comment: ...I would have literally never known that. Thank you! Now I just have to global a number of other variables. =)

Comment: @omicronlyrae: The `global` will only remove the sympton, but won't heal the cause. Instead start to group code into functions and pass values via parameters. If parameters become to complex, use structures.